# Windows Phone 8 - Keeping background location tracking active beyond four hours

Tags: windows-phone-8, geolocation, location, background-process, mobile-application

I'm in the process of developing a WP8 app that makes use of the background location tracking abilities provided by the OS. The idea is to monitor the users position and to notify them when they are near certain types of places.

So far it all seems to work fine and when running the location tracking works as I would expect.

The problem is, it seems that the phone times out background apps after around four hours, stopping the location tracking.

I can understand why Microsoft did it, to preserve battery life etc. But there's not much point having a background location tracking app that has to be manually restarted every four hours! If a user chooses to run this app and is made aware of the potential battery hit, surely it should be able to run indefinitely - to a point of course, if the system runs out of resources or similar then that's fair enough.

Does anyone have any experience with this? There must be hundreds of others apps in the store that have run into this issue I would have thought? And presumably there must be some way of keeping the location tracking running?

I've tried periodically updating the live tile (using a DispatcherTimer) while the tracking is running but this doesn't seem to be enough to keep the app alive either :(

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to achieve your desired behavior. The app will be deactivated under anye of following conditions:

- The app stops actively tracking location. An app stops tracking location by removing event handlers for the PositionChanged and StatusChanged events of the Geolocator class or by calling the Stop() method of the GeoCoordinateWatcher class.
- The app has run in the background for 4 hours without user interaction.
- Battery Saver is active.
- Device memory is low.
- The user disables Location Services on the phone.
- Another app begins running in the background.

Source: [Running location-tracking apps in the background for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681691%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

What you could do is to show a toast notification before app is deactivated advising the user, and make him navigate back to the app, extending the period for other 4 hours that way.

There is no way to keep it running without any user interaction.

Comment: That's a massive limitation of the OS then. Guessing that's why there's no apps like Google Latitude on WP8 then that are on iOS and android! Wouldn't be much use for mapping your location over time if it kept having to be manually restarted.